# Multiple variant.cpp entries for same physical pin

Tags: pins, spi, arduino-zero, samd21g, dac

Some `variant.cpp` files have more than one entry that points to the same physical pin. For example (from Arduino Zero's file):

```
// 14..19 - Analog pins
// --------------------
{ PORTA,  2, PIO_ANALOG, PIN_ATTR_ANALOG, ADC_Channel0, NOT_ON_PWM, NOT_ON_TIMER, EXTERNAL_INT_2 }, // ADC/AIN[0]

...

// 43..45 - Alternate use of A0 (DAC output), 44 SWCLK, 45, SWDIO
{ PORTA,  2, PIO_ANALOG, PIN_ATTR_ANALOG, DAC_Channel0, NOT_ON_PWM, NOT_ON_TIMER, EXTERNAL_INT_2 }, // DAC/VOUT
```

The first entry sets up the pin as a regular analog input pin on A0. The second entry sets it up as a DAC on pin IDE pin 43.

The corresponding `variant.h` file defines the DAC pin and A0 as entry 14, rather than 43. I also have seen plenty of examples online that use the DAC via A0 when working with an Arduino Zero.

```
/*
 * Analog pins
 */
#define PIN_A0               (14ul)
#define PIN_A1               (15ul)
#define PIN_A2               (16ul)
#define PIN_A3               (17ul)
#define PIN_A4               (18ul)
#define PIN_A5               (19ul)
#define PIN_DAC0             (14ul)
```

Finally, I see other variants, like [this one](https://github.com/sparkfun/SparkFun_Qwiic_Micro_SAMD21E/blob/master/Firmware/Arduino_Board_Files/SparkFun_Qwiic_Micro/variant.cpp) that don't even bother to create a DAC-specific entry. So presumably it doesn't actually matter? If not, then why is it in the Arduino Zero `variant.cpp` file at all?

A related question: How does using a pin for multiple purposes work? For instance, if I had a pin I've configured for SPI MOSI (in `variant.cpp`), and I wanted to also use it for PWM (given the datasheet says the pin is on a SERCOM and a timer), do I actually need two entries in `variant.cpp` and thus two different IDE pins to use in my sketches (one that has a pin type of `PIO_SERCOM` and another with `PIO_PWM`)? I can think of plenty of times working with an Arduino UNO, for instance, where I've just used the same IDE pin number for general IO as well as SPI (MOSI).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `analogWrite` function checks the `PIN_ATTR_ANALOG` attribute from pin description in variant.cpp to determine if the pin has DAC capability. Then it checks if the pin is `ADC_Channel0` or `DAC_Channel0`. This is unnecessary and redundant. There is no other use for `DAC_Channel0`.

In Arduino SAMD core and derived cores the pin 'map' in variant.cpp defines pin capabilities used by Arduino core. It is not a complete copy of the mux table from the datasheet. In some variant.cpp files comments contain the additional mux options of the pin.

For PWM the analogWrite function configures the pin and for SPI, the SPI library configures the pin.

If you want to use the pin for other SERCOM function, the function `pinPeripheral` is used to set up the pin. Here is [a tutorial](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/SamdSercom).

Arduino core doesn't support a configuration of a different wave output then analogWrite. To configure a different wave output or capture, a third party library or direct registers configuration is necessary.

The Arduino `pinPeripheral(pin, peripheral)` function uses the variant.cpp mapping and the possible parameters are:

```
PIO_EXTINT=0,     /* The pin is controlled by the associated signal of peripheral A. */
PIO_ANALOG,       /* The pin is controlled by the associated signal of peripheral B. */
PIO_SERCOM,       /* The pin is controlled by the associated signal of peripheral C. */
PIO_SERCOM_ALT,   /* The pin is controlled by the associated signal of peripheral D. */
PIO_TIMER,        /* The pin is controlled by the associated signal of peripheral E. */
PIO_TIMER_ALT,    /* The pin is controlled by the associated signal of peripheral F. */
PIO_COM,          /* The pin is controlled by the associated signal of peripheral G. */
PIO_AC_CLK,       /* The pin is controlled by the associated signal of peripheral H. */
PIO_DIGITAL,      /* The pin is controlled by PORT. */
```

If you are good with the Arduino variant.cpp configuration, then for direct registers access configuration the pin 'map' from variant.cpp and the `pinPeripheral` function can be at help if the pin should not be hardcoded. Example from peripherals setup for 'phase cutting' with a Triac [in my project](https://github.com/jandrassy/Regulator/blob/master/TriacLib/TriacLib.h):

```
const PinDescription& pinDesc = g_APinDescription[triacPin]; // Arduino pin description
TCC = (Tcc*) GetTC(pinDesc.ulPWMChannel);
uint8_t tcChannel = GetTCChannelNumber(pinDesc.ulPWMChannel);
bool periF = (pinDesc.ulPinAttribute & PIN_ATTR_TIMER_ALT);

// setup the pin as TCC wave out pin
pinPeripheral(triacPin, periF ? PIO_TIMER_ALT : PIO_TIMER);

TCC->CC[tcChannel].reg = PULSE_PERIOD;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. It doesn’t quite answer the question though about how a variant could get away with not specifying the DAC alternative for A0 (PA02). For instance, the A0 entry doesn’t even specify the DAC channel as the alternate entry does. If A0 were passed to some function that ultimately looks at the channel configuration, it wouldn’t have the right value.

Comment: sorry, I missed the ADC_Channel0/DAC_Channel0 difference. I enhanced the answer with a new first paragraph

Comment: Thank you! A small side question: What is the consequence of having two different pins on the same timer and channel? For instance, on the SAMD21E, both PA06 and PA30 (SWCLK) have TCC1/WO[0] as the only timer option in the SERCOM mux table.

Comment: SERCOM is SERialCOMunication so UART, SPI, I2C. you can't set two different pins on the same timer and channel. you can map them on the same timer and channel, but then they can't be used at the same time for PWM